# Find the form of all elements commuting with $(1,2)(3,4)$ in $S_n$. ("Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, solution-verification

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
The following problem is Problem 6 on p.90 in Herstein's book:

> Problem 6:
> (a) Find the number of conjugates of $(1,2)(3,4)$ in $S_n$, $n\geq 4$.
> (b) Find the form of all elements commuting with $(1,2)(3,4)$ in $S_n$.

I solved this problem, but I am not sure my solution is ok or not.

My solution uses the following theorem:

> Theorem 2.11.1:
> If $G$ is a finite group, then $c_a=\frac{o(G)}{o(N(a))}$; in other words, the number of elements conjugate to $a$ in $G$ is the index of the normalizer of $a$ in $G$.

I solved this problem as follows:

> (a) If we choose arbitrary distinct $4$ elements $a,b,c,d$ from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, we get $3$ distinct permutations of type $(2,2)$:
> $(a,b)(c,d),(a,c)(b,d),(a,d)(b,c)$.
> So, the answer is $3\binom{n}{4}$.
>
> (b) Let $N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4))$ be the normalizer of $(1,2)(3,4)$ in $S_n$.
> Then, by Theorem 2.11.1, $\frac{o(S_n)}{o(N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4)))}=3\binom{n}{4}$.
> So, $o(N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4)))=\frac{o(S_n)}{3\binom{n}{4}}=8(n-4)!$.
> Let $A:=\{\sigma\in S_4\mid\sigma\text{ is an element which commutes with }(1,2)(3,4)\}$.
> Let $B:=\{\tau\in S_n\mid\tau\text{ is an element which leaves all of }1,2,3,4\text{ fixed. }\}$.
> Let $C:=\{\sigma\tau\mid\sigma\in A, \tau\in B\}$.
> Let $\mu\in C$.
> Then, $\mu$ commutes with $(1,2)(3,4)$.
> So, $C\subset N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4))$.
> $\#A=o(N_{S_4}((1,2)(3,4)))=8(4-4)!=8$.
> $\#B=(n-4)!$.
> So, $\#A\times\#B=\#C=o(N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4)))$.
> So, $C=N_{S_n}((1,2)(3,4))$.
> So, $\mu\in S_n$ commutes with $(1,2)(3,4)$ if and only if $\mu\in C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems good to me!
You may also want to notice that $A\cong D_4$, as $A$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(1324)$ and $(12)(1324)(12)= (1423)$.

Comment: Desperado, Thank you very much for your answer and the information $A=D_4$.